# Calling an Activity from asyncTask doInBackground

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

hello i am calling a `base activity class` from a seperate `asyncTask class`, when i run application on **one device with android 4.4.2**  it works fine but when i run it on phone having **android 5.0**  then at this point of calling activity from asyncTask app crashes. please tell if any one have solution?

```
public abstract class AbstractGetNameTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void>  
{
private static final String TAG = "TokenInfoTask";
protected ActivityLogin mActivity;
public static String GOOGLE_USER_DATA="No_data";
protected String mScope;
protected String mEmail;
protected int mRequestCode;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
 private Context mContext;



AbstractGetNameTask(ActivityLogin activity, String email, String      
scope,Context context) {
    this.mActivity = activity;
    this.mScope = scope;
    this.mEmail = email;
    this.mContext=context;

}   

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    pDialog.setTitle("Loading....");
    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.setMax(100);
    pDialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}




@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
try {
fetchNameFromProfileServer();   // here in this method i start new activity

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        onError("Following Error occured, please try again. "
                + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        onError("Bad response: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

my android manifest has

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

but it never bother me for another apps

Comment: where is your logcat??

Comment: i told you in debug mode it works fine... but on installing apk it does not work

Comment: Put the logs what you are catching in `try-catch` block.

Comment: when the app is installed it still logs to logcat.

Comment: Also it is not a good idea to start activity from do in background do it on postExecute

Comment: So, why AsyncTask providing `onPostExecute()` ?

Comment: post the code of `fetchNameFromProfileServer`

Comment: ok i got degen sharew thanks

Comment: so i cant start activity do in background right?

Comment: @Degen i have updated my question please have look at it

Comment: You have not added the code I asked you.

Answer (score 0):

You should start activity from your `onPostExecute`. You just need to return the result from `fetchNameFromProfileServer()` instead of starting the activity from there and pass the result to `onPostExecute` and there start you activity.

Comment: Can you paste the code here. how are you doing this ?

Comment: my real problem is it works on lower version of android say 4.4.2 on one phone but not on phone having android 5.0 . I have two deveices

Comment: and in my manifest-  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Comment: should not you use targetSdkVersion 21. if you have to use it in android 5.0?